# Are there any Themes for flexigrid?

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Are there any other themes for flexigrid other then the default theme?

What the best way to change the default flexigrid theme?

Comment: There are **42** different themes....

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:
http://www.flexigrid-asp.net/demo/skinning.aspx

and here:
http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/117-share-your-themes/

Simple theming like in the example above can be done by changing the flexigrid.css file and a few images.

If your requirments are more complicated then you will need to dive deeper into flexigrid code.